# Element ITEM is not allowed in MENU

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.2-froyo, android-menu

I'm trying to make a customized options menu. After using this code I get: **Element item is not allowed here**

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <item android:id="@+id/morsoid_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/morsoid_close"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

Inspired by: [Android dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html)

Answer (score 14):

I dont know whether it makes a difference, but did you place you menu in res/menu and not in res/layout?

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. Certainly in IntelliJ Idea 11.0.2 it kept displaying errors in my menu layout. Once I moved it under res/menu all was OK. +1

Answer (score 3):

Try leaving out the layout attributes. Here is the example from the documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

**Edit** - also make sure you are using a `MenuInflater` as the guide suggests:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Using a `LayoutInflater` will cause `<menu>` to be interpreted as a view element, when it is actually a menu resource.

Comment: I've tryied, but another error is shown: **layout_width should be defined** (same for height) :(

Comment: You are probably using a layout inflater instead of a menu inflater.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure you are talking about a compile error, or the errors shown in your development system while in the layout file.

Using `Idea IntelliJ (10.5)` I got that error while pasting the example code shown above into the menu.xml file.

However after building the project, it disappeared. I still see the layout_width / height errors you see when editing the menu.xml file but it does not affect the build or runtime behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of an old question but I thought I'd put my solution here since I experienced this in 2019:

I was getting a warning in Android Studio saying "Element item is not allowed here" when putting an `<item>` inside a `<menu>`. It turns out my problem was that in my src/main/res/layout folder, rather than in my src/main/res/menu folder.